# How do I get Intellisense on the expression of a foreach loop within a Razor section?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, intellisense

I can't seem to get intellisense to load up my Model's properties when using within a foreach loop in a Razor section.

```
@model Test.Models.TestViewModel
@section AdditionalPanel{
    @foreach(var meeting in Model.meetings){

    }
}
```

In the code above, when I press `.` after Model, intellisense does not appear.

What's strange is that it works within other statements (even within for loop), and also works outside of the section block.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem - so it's not just you - but no solution!

Answer (score 0):

the way you are trying to access Model.meetings, it is not possible though if you want to achieve the same you have to assign meetings object into ViewData and then you can read it in your view and loop through. for example :

```
meetings = ViewData["meetingCollectionObject"] as Meetings;
@foreach(var meeting in meetings){

  }
```

Don't forget to add namespace for the meeting class in your view

Comment: I'm actually able to access Model.meetings using my code without adding it to ViewData because it's a strongly-typed view. It's just that the Intellisense is not showing the properties in this very specific scenario.

Another note is that the code is fully working if I manually type in the property names, it's just a bit inconvenient to do so without Intellisense.